# Apply CSS except for child with specific ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Consider the following mark up:

```
<ul>
 <li class="search-results">
   <p>Style me please</p>
   <span id="not-me-please">Do not style me</span>
 </li>
```

And the CSS:

```
 ul li.search-results {color:green}
```

Obviously both the paragraph and the span will have green text but is there a way to use the :not selector so that the span doesn't get the styling?

Comment: You are not targeting the paragraph and the span individually here - you are formatting the list item itself. So while doing that, using `:not()` makes little sense here. You could switch to setting the color for all _child_ elements of the LI - then you can exclude that specific span via `:not()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class and exclude the `#not-me-please` element as below, but I would not recommend this approach as it can be considered bad practice.

```css
 ul li.search-results > *:not(#not-me-please) {color:green}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="search-results">
   <p>Style me please</p>
   <span id="not-me-please">Do not style me</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

### Recommendation

Either add a specific class to the elements intended to be green (i.e., `<p class="search-results_label">`) or target the `p` tags directly (i.e., `ul li.search-results > p`).

> Note that I would not advise targeting the global ul tag directly either.